# Apartment::TenantNotFound (Error while connecting to tenant 34: FATAL: database "34" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, apartment-gem

I am using `ros-apartment gem` for multi tenancy in rails application. I have deployed the application on AWS and sometime I get below error:

> Apartment::TenantNotFound (Error while connecting to tenant 34: FATAL:  database "34" does not exist):

And the backtrack of this error is:

```
ros-apartment (2.9.0) lib/apartment/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:268:in `raise_connect_error!'
ros-apartment (2.9.0) lib/apartment/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:189:in `rescue in connect_to_new'
ros-apartment (2.9.0) lib/apartment/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:178:in `connect_to_new'
ros-apartment (2.9.0) lib/apartment/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:76:in `block in switch!'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
ros-apartment (2.9.0) lib/apartment/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:75:in `switch!'
ros-apartment (2.9.0) lib/apartment/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:88:in `switch'
ros-apartment (2.9.0) lib/apartment/elevators/generic.rb:22:in `call'
remotipart (1.4.2) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:32:in `call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call
```

Also I don't have the database with name 34, I have added Generic elevators to select the database from subdomain.

My tenant switching code in Generic elevator code in `apartment.rb` is as follows:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use Apartment::Elevators::Generic, lambda { |request|
  _host = request.host.split('.').first
  if ExcludedSubdomains.subdomains.include?(_host)
    Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]["database"]
  else
    _host
  end
}
```

Because of this issue my server needs too long time to respond.

Comment: You can exclude the 34 from `ExcludedSubdomains` array

Answer (score 1):

I am facing this issue because my host IP start from `34.xx.xx.xx` as per code it return first subdomain it consider 34 is a first subdomain and because of that it search for 34 database and issue occcured